# Groovy in Active Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following groovy cod to display in Active Choice Parameter some folder names and if the folder contains the ".a7" file display the file, if not,should post a error message.
**My problem is that my cod don't display the error message if the folder "a7.nativ" is missing and implicit the path to ".a7" file(/mnt/a7/v5.5/a7.nativ/v5.5/55.a7) is interrupted.**
Can somebody help me please?
This is the cod:

```
 Build=[]
path2 = "/mnt/cc7/v5.5/a7.nativ/v5.5/"
new File(path2).eachFileMatch(~/.*.a7/) {
              Build.add(it.getName())                
}  
if(Build){
return Build
} else {
return ["There is no file to display"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional step that checks if given path exists. Otherwise, you implicitly assume that the given folder always exists. Consider the following modification:

```
def build = []
def path2 = "/mnt/cc7/v5.5/a7.nativ/v5.5/"
def file = new File(path2)

if (!file.exists()) {
    return ["There is no file to display"]
}

file.eachFileMatch(~/.*.a7/) {
    build.add(it.getName())
}

return build ?: ["There is no file to display"]
```